# background image not add inside the div

Tags: html, css, jsp

I`ve tried to add a background image to the div ,but the image does not show inside the div but the background image work correctly.I have followed several tutorials to solve this problem, but no one to support me to solve this. Please help me fix this problem.thank you. here is my part of code..

inside jsp...

```
<div class="six">
        <div class="six_one">
            //some thing
        </div>
        <div class="six_two">
          //some thing
        </div>
```

my css part...

```
 .six{
 height: 650px; 
 display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
 display: flex;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 background-image: url("/imgs/c1.jpg");
 background-size: cover;
 }
 .six_one{

 -ms-flex: 60%; /* IE10 */
 flex: 60%; 
 padding-left:40px;


 }
 .six_two{

 -ms-flex: 40%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 40%; 
  padding: 20px;


  }
```

Comment: do you have any errors in the console ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code that is causing the problem. Probably the URL is wrong

Answer (score 0):

When working with links in HTML, there are a few things you can try if the said link does not.

1. Pressing F12 on most browsers will bring up the developer console, from there you can check what network errors, CSS, JS errors are in your code, you can also edit the overall website from the console and check if the changes are what is required
2. Use a tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) to check what items are loaded by your website and what items failed. The failed items will be in red[400-500 range, and in some cases may even be white, showing a redirect if your site is set up like that
3. If you are using an IDE like Visual Studio, simply dragging the image to the js file will create a corrected path to it.

if you you need more information, to can check [W3School's relative path in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) guide to understand this a bit better.
Here is a snippet from the site.
[image: Relative File Paths in HTML]

Comment: thak you sir.I slove the problem

Comment: If the answer is what helper you, then mark it as such to help others who come to the same issue

Comment: The reasion was URL...I put the images inside the my css folder and put only image file name.jpg then work it